# Manejo de propiedades heterogéneas en objetos provenientes de bases de datos no relacionales

Tags: javascript, nodejs, condiciones, estructuras-de-datos, rendimiento

Estoy trabajando con objetos provenientes de una base de datos no relacional, y me he encontrado con la situación de que la estructura de datos no es homogénea. En particular, algunas propiedades pueden tener nombres diferentes, lo que resulta en código repetitivo para validar y obtener la versión correcta de cada propiedad.

Consideremos los siguientes tres ejemplos de objetos que representan información sobre una persona:

```
{
Nombre
lastName
age
}

{
nombre
lastName
age
}

{
name
lastName
age
}
```

Hasta ahora, he ideado algunas soluciones para abordar este problema:

**Solución 1:** Validación en cada punto de la aplicación:

```
 const name = persona.name | persona.Name | persona.nombre
```

**Solución 2:** Función encapsulada para la obtención de propiedades:

```
getName(persona)=> persona.name | persona.Name | persona.nombre
```

**Solución 3:** Normalización de datos a través de una función:

```js
const personMock = { nombre: 'pedro', lastName: 'correa', age: 20 };

const personNormalizer = (person) => {
  const name = person?.nombre || person?.name || person?.Name;
  const { age, lastName } = person;
  return { name, lastName, age };
};

const getPersonById = () => {
  return personNormalizer(personMock);
};

const personData = getPersonById();

console.log(personData);
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cuál sería la mejor práctica para abordar este problema? ¿Existen otras soluciones o enfoques que podrían ser más eficientes y limpios? Agradezco cualquier orientación o experiencia que puedan compartir.

Comment: Como esta descripto esto, esta basado en opiniones... a mi me gusta el helper.. pero capaz a otro le gusta otra cosa.. asi como esta, esta pregutna no va con el formato del sitio..

Comment: creo que si va la pregunta, algunos te podran decir que el helper hace gasto de procesamiento al pedo cuando necesitas la propiedad normalizada, quiero saber la opinion de los demas,  para conocer soluciones o patrones mejores que den una mejor solucion a este problema.

Comment: es que, no entendiste.. hay un motivo de cierre que es BASADA EN OPINIONES... que es justamente, lo que estas pidiendo.. las opiniones no van con el formato de este sitio.. aca tenes que aceptar una respuesta, y no vas a poder aceptar opiniones...

Comment: Como toda solucion, en el codigo puede tener muchas soluciones y muchas respuestas, quiero conocer si hay una forma o patron mas optimo que esto, una opinion puede ser sobre algo que tiene un mismo resultado sin afectar el performance,  pero depende del estilo de alguien como usar en un proyecto pascalCase o camelCase. En este caso no es solo de estilo si no que en caso de procesamiento de gran cantidad de request puede afectar quizas mucho o poco el performance de la aplicacion. Me parece muy mala onda tu falta de empatia hacer cerrar una pregunta valida es muy facil

Comment: es que, tu mismo en la pregunta, y en los comentarios, estas diciendo que necesitas opiniones.. aca no hay una pregunta valida. Pero no te quedes con mi "mala onda" (que solo sigo las reglas)... pregunta en meta, si esta pregunta es valida o no.. y en tal caso, la reabrimos...

Comment: y porfa, lee el enlace en el motivo de cierre, asi esta claro el porque del mismo...

Comment: Lo que yo no entiendo, es como llegaste a esa situación de tener propiedades con nombre distintos

Comment: como lo explique antes, en base de datos relacionales, la estructura de los datos que se guardan no son un contrato fijo como en una base de datos relacional, entonces los objectos que se guardan en las colecciones por x o y razon pueden tener algun cambio en su estructura pero los servicios deben tener retrocompatibilidad con la estructura vieja, este problema pasa en muchas empresas.